# Evaluate the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}{f(x)-f(2x)\over x}dx$, where $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Find $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{f(x)-f(2x)\over x}\, \mathrm{d}x$$ if $f\in C([0,\infty])$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}{f(x)=L}$.

I tried denoting $\displaystyle \int{f(x)\over x}dx=F(x)$, but I don't know what to do with $F(\infty)-F(0)$. I also tried somehow to use l'Hopital's rule but don't seem to come by a plausible justification for it, nor do I arrive at a clear expression. I would really appreciate your help in this.

Comment: this integral can take any value...

Comment: @Tryss Really? What's an _example_ where it takes a value other than $-L\log(2)$?

Comment: A simple exemple : $f(x) = L$, and the integral is $0$.

Comment: @Tryss Right. I made an error - see corrected version of my answer. It's not true that the value has to be what I said. But it does have to be $(f(0)-L)\log(2)$, can't be "any value"...

Comment: See [Frullani's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are possible singularities at the origin and at infinity; by definition the integral is the limit of $\int_\delta^A$ as $\delta\to0$ and $A\to\infty$. You have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_\delta^A\frac{f(t)}{t}-\int_\delta^A\frac{f(2t)}{t}&=\int_\delta^A\frac{f(t)}{t}-\int_{2\delta}^{2A}\frac{f(t)}t
\\&=\int_{\delta}^{2\delta}\frac{f(t)}t-\int_{A}^{2A}\frac{f(t)}t
\\&=\int_1^2\frac{f(\delta t)}{t}-\int_1^2\frac{f(At)}{t}
\\&\to(f(0)-L)\log(2),
\end{eqnarray*}$$
by uniform convergence on $[1,2]$.

Comment: So, does the final answer contains $f(0)$ or not?

Comment: @meitar Sorry, was in a hurry. The final answer is $(f(0)-L)\log(2)$. I'll clean things up...

Comment: @Meitar Ok, see if you like that better...

Answer (score 7):

If one assumes that $f$ is sufficiently well-behaved (and in particular, differentiable), one can solve this by differentiating under the integral sign (this is sometimes called *Feynman's trick*).

Define
$$I(a) := \int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x) - f(a x)}{x} \,dx.$$
Differentiating with respect to $a$ (and justifying passing the derivative sign through the improper integral) gives (for $a > 0)$) that
\begin{align}
I'(a)
&= \frac{d}{da} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x) - f(a x)}{x} \,dx \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d}{da} \left(\frac{f(x) - f(a x)}{x}\right) dx \\
&= -\int_0^{\infty} f'(ax) \,dx \\
&= -\left.\frac{1}{a} f(ax)\right\vert_0^{\infty} \\
&= \frac{1}{a}(f(0) - L) .
\end{align}
By the F.T.C., integrating w.r.t. $a$ gives
$$I(2) - I(1) = \int_1^2 \frac{1}{a}(f(0) = L)\, da = (f(0) - L) \log a \vert_1^2 = (f(0) - L) \log 2.$$
On the other hand, $I(2)$ is the integral we want to evaluate and
$$I(1) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x) - f(x)}{x} dx = 0.$$
Putting this all together gives, as desired,
$$\color{#bf0000}{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x) - f(2 x)}{x} \,dx = (f(0) - L) \log 2}.$$

---

Here's a different way to present essentially the same argument: The integrand is a difference of the values of a particular expression at two points, which is precisely the form of one side of the F.T.C. Reverse-engineering gives
$$\frac{f(x) - f(2 x)}{x} = -\int_1^2 f'(y x) \,dy.$$
Justifying a reversal of the order of integration again gives
\begin{align}
\color{#bf0000}{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x) - f(2 x)}{x} dx}
&=  \int_0^{\infty} \left[-\int_1^2 f'(y x) \,dy\right] dx \\
&= -\int_1^2 \int_0^{\infty} f'(y x) \,dx \,dy \\
&= -\int_1^2 \left.\frac{1}{y} f(y x)\right\vert_0^{\infty} dy \\
&= -(L - f(0)) \int_1^2 \frac{dy}{y} \\
&\color{#bf0000}{= (f(0) - L) \log 2} .
\end{align}

More generally, the same argument gives (for $f$ satisfying the same conditions as in the question) that
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(bx) - f(ax)}{x} dx = (L - f(0)) \log \frac{b}{a}.$$

Comment: I believe the general formula in the last line of the display (or, at least, one very similar to it) has a name, but I could neither recall nor find it. I'd be grateful if someone could remind me.

Comment: I believe the general formula is Frullani's.

Comment: @kobe Yes, that's it, thank you!

Comment: @Travis Now how do you justify differentiating under the integral sign? Or reversing the order of integration?

Comment: @Travis Or for that matter, how do you even show $I(\alpha)$ _exists_ in the first place?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You're right that this probably requires some niceness condition on $f$. For reversing the order of integration, for example, I think $f' \in L^1([0, \infty))$ should suffice.

Comment: @Travis Yes, that's enough for the Fubini. Not clear to me that that's enough for the differentiation under the integral sign. I guess I'm curious why we like these arguments better than the other one. The other one proves much more, and also seems much simpler. (This one isn't even a proof yet, until we add those "justifications". The justifications are really not optional, this is the sort of improper integral situation where things _can_ go wrong. As we see from the guy who said the answer is $\int_0^\infty f(t)/t - \int_0^\infty f(t)/t=0$; that would be fine if we could "justify" it...)

Comment: I don't know "we" is (is that in particular a complaint about upvote counts?), but I don't claim that the argument in my answer is better or otherwise preferable that yours, and I won't speculate on the preferences of others.

Comment: Also, like many other answers on this site, this answer is not intended to be a detailed, self-contained proof (the hedge at the beginning of the proof is supposed to emphasize this); rather, I wrote it to expose an (in my view) interesting connection with a circle of ideas that's interesting but underexposed. Of course, I mention the justifications precisely to point out what is needed to make this a complete, detailed proof---if they were optional, I wouldn't have bothered to mention them in the first place.